# Send empty string through HTTP to ASP.NET Core endpoint resource

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a simple endpoint that takes in a single string as its template resource. I want this endpoint to be able to handle two situations, one where the input string is non-empty, and one where the string being sent through HTTP is empty.

The trouble is, when I attempt to send an empty string to this resource I get a 405.

Is there any way to enable this endpoint to be able to handling both of these situations or will I need a second endpoint that doesn't have a resource?

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
    {
         //do stuff
    }
```

At the moment a HTTP request with `{endpointUrl}/{id}` will work correctly, but `{endpoint}/` will produce a 405. I want to be able to handle both of these situations, preferably with the same endpoint. An empty string will return a default value, whereas an actual id will return data specific to that id.

Comment: Have you tryied with `[HttpGet("{id?}")]`

Comment: @spzvtbg I had no idea template params were nullable, that's worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach two `HttpGet` attributes to the same method like so:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[HttpGet("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

In case `{endpointUrl}/` is called, `id` will be null.